NextJS 14 - Error when using fs inside app router
I am using the fs module to read markdown files to later display them. Below you can find my implementation:
import fs from "fs";
import matter from "gray-matter";

export default function getHubMetadata() {
  const folder = "hubs";
  const files = fs.readdirSync(folder);
  const hubs = files.filter((file) => file.endsWith(".md"));

  const hubPosts = hubs.map((filename) => {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(`${folder}/${filename}`, "utf8");
    const matterResult = matter(fileContent);
    return matterResult;
  });

  return hubPosts;
}

I am using this function inside two different routes /project-hub and /project-hub/[slug]. The function works perfectly on my PC, but when run on Vercel only the /project-hub route works, the other throws following error:
ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'hubs'

I moved the "hubs" folders location several times and tried using the path module but to no avail, it is still not working on Vercel.

I found a similar issue here they were able to solve their issue by following this article.
